# Use PHP tags within a .HTML document to link PHP files

Tags: php, html, mysql, syntax

I am creating my first website with a Login and Register User system.

I have created all the HTML files and styled my website so the front end is complete with all the forms.

My Index.html should include the following to run a PHP file thats links to all other files to connect to the database.

```
<?php 
  include 'core/init.php';
?>
```

I simply including the PHP tags in my html document but it does not run, should my index.html file be a .php file removing the html tags. I did change the index.html to .php but it didn't load using MAMP servers.

Any advice and suggestions are welcome, thanks (Y)

Comment: Do other PHP pages load at all? Please elaborate `does not run`, any errors? Try running a `test.php` file with the line: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete index.html, then the server will look for index.php, which you can treat like a normal HTML file containing php

Comment: Thank you for replying, I deleted the index.html file. The index.php file is not loading via localhost. This may be due to my document structure,

    <?php 
       include 'core/init.php';
    ?>
    <html>
      Content
    </html>

Comment: what exaclty happens when you call just http://localhost/ (404 Page not found error, any php errors, blank page...)? what happens when you do http://localhost/index.php ? Your document structure is right. Maybe paste the complete one to a paste tool and share us the link

Comment: It has managed to work, the load times were really slow. Thank you, I have a index.php that connects to other php files. But for some reason my CSS does not look the same :/

Comment: sorry, but that is not enough information. show the code (css in your file and css that you see in the webserver). where is your css defined, what is the difference,...?

Comment: Sorry, I have found the solution, I needed to include (!DOCTYPE html> after the PHP. Thank you for your all your help (Y)